# Python Multithreading/processing gains for inserts to different tables in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I've been pouring over everywhere I can to find an answer to this, but can't seem to find anything:

I've got a batch update to a MySQL database that happens every few minutes, with Python handling the ETL work (I'm pulling data from web API's into the MySQL system).

I'm trying to get a sense of what kinds of potential impact (be it positive or negative) I'd see by using either multithreading or multiprocessing to do multiple connections & inserts of the data simultaneously. Each worker (be it thread or process) would be updating a different table from any other worker.

At the moment I'm only updating a half-dozen tables with a few thousand records each, but this needs to be scalable to dozens of tables and hundreds of thousands of records each.

Every other resource I can find out there addresses doing multithreading/processing to the same table, not a distinct table per worker. I get the impression I would definitely want to use multithreading/processing, but it seems everyone's addressing the one-table use case.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too broad to answer concisely. It seems you're asking about two separate subjects - will writing to separate MySQL tables speed it up, and is python multithreading the way to go. For the python part, since you're probably doing mostly IO, you should look at [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), and [ultramysql](https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql). As for the MySQL part, you'll have to wait for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

For one I wrote in C#, I decided the best work partitioning was each "source" having a thread for extraction, one for each transform "type", and one to load the transformed data to each target.

In my case, I found multiple threads per source just ended up saturating the source server too much; it became less responsive overall (to even non-ETL queries) and the extractions didn't really finish any faster since they ended up competing with each other on the source. Since retrieving the remote extract was more time consuming than the local (in memory) transform, I was able to pipeline the extract results from all sources through one transformer thread/queue (per transform "type"). Similarly, I only had a single target to load the data to, so having multiple threads there would have just monopolized the target.
*(Some details omitted/simplified for brevity, and due to poor memory.)*

...but I'd think we'd need more details about what your ETL process does.